# Weighted Average to combine data into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to achieve weighted average data in single row. This is what my current data look like

| Name | Position | Id | score1 | score2 | list | lastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | POS1 | 12345 | 10 | 20 | 2 | YUI |
| ABC | POS2 | 12345 | 20 | 10 | 5 | YUI |
| ABC | POS3 | 12345 | 20 | 30 | 7 | YUI |
| ABC | POS4 | 12345 | 10 | 50 | 2 | YUI |
| XYZ | POS1 | 67890 | 5 | 10 | 5 | OPR |
| XYZ | POS2 | 67890 | 30 | 20 | 3 | OPR |
| XYZ | POS3 | 67890 | 40 | 40 | 1 | OPR |
| XYZ | POS4 | 67890 | 20 | 10 | 2 | OPR |

Desire output should be like below

| Name | Position | Id | score1 | score2 | list | lastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | POS1, POS2, PO3, POS4 | 12345 | 17.5 | 25 | 16 | YUI |
| XYZ | POS1, POS2, PO3, POS4 | 67890 | 17.72 | 15.45 | 11 | OPR |

Score1 is calculated as sum(score1 * list/ sum(list)) based on id

For ABC (ID 12345) Score1= 10*(2/16) + 20*(5/16) + 20*(7/16) + 10*(2/16) = 17.5

Score2= 20*(2/16) + 10*(5/16) + 30*(7/16) + 50*(2/16) = 25

List =  2+ 5+ 7+2 =  16

For XYZ(ID 67890) Score1= 5*(5/11) + 30*(3/11) + 40*(1/11) + 20*(2/11) = 17.72

Score2= 10*(5/11) + 20*(3/11) + 40*(1/11) + 10*(2/11) = 15.45

List =  5+3+1+2 = 11

Position data are string aggregate of different positions. Position data are not same always, it could be 4 rows for one and 2 rows for other.

Any help would be really great, thank you!

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On SQL Server 2017 or greater:

```
SELECT 
  Name, 
  Position = STRING_AGG(Position, ', '), 
  Id,  
  Score1 = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(Score1 * 1.0 * list) / SUM(list)), 
  Score2 = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(Score2 * 1.0 * list) / SUM(list)),
  list = SUM(list), 
  lastName
FROM dbo.Scores
GROUP BY Name, Id, lastName;
```

Output:

| Name | Position | Id | Score1 | Score2 | list | lastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | POS1, POS2, POS3, POS4 | 12345 | 17.50 | 25.00 | 16 | YUI |
| XYZ | POS1, POS2, POS3, POS4 | 67890 | 17.73 | 15.45 | 11 | OPR |

On older versions, same results, just uglier and less efficient:

```
SELECT 
  Name, 
  Position = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Position
    FROM dbo.Scores
    WHERE Id = s.Id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]',
                            N'varchar(max)'),1,1,''),
  Id,  
  Score1 = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(Score1 * 1.0 * list) / SUM(list)), 
  Score2 = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(Score2 * 1.0 * list) / SUM(list)),
  list = SUM(list), 
  lastName
FROM dbo.Scores AS s
GROUP BY Name, Id, lastName;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=58e592e3d261151d6305a4f938a0db3f)

Comment: @Mehul sure thing, if you want to guarantee `POS1, POS2` ordering etc., you need to have some column that can determine the ordering (if it's anything but alphabetical). In the current solutions it's arbitrary / luck of the draw.

Comment: Sure thing, @Aaron, for now I am pretty much okay by twisting the query you provided as per my need. I just needed that starting point. Your query helped a lot!! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you could use a join with a sub query for sum list

```
select a.name, STRING_AGG(a.Position, ','), a.id,   sum(a.score1*a.list)/t.tot_x_list, sum(a.score2*(a.list/t.tot_x_list))
from my_table a
inner join (
    select id, sum(list) tot_x_list 
    from my_table 
    group by id
) t on t.id = a.id 
group by a.id
```